# MySQL Command-line client

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install and use the MySQL Command-line client on windows,  as documented here: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

After installing MySQL I found a program "MySQL Shell". When I run it, it prompts

```
MySQL Shell 8.0.14

Copyright (c) 2016, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.

MySQL JS>
```

instead of prompting "Shell". Is that the same tool? how do I run it in Shell mode?

If it's not the same tool, where can the install for the one I'm looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want **MySQL Client**.

Looks like you installed [**MySQL Shell**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/), enter `\sql` to allow `SHOW DATABASES;` command.

Comment: Thanks.
Can you add a link for **MySQL Client** Install for windows? it's embarrassing but we're looking for it and can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your in shell but already using MySQL. If you type in:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

What does it say?

If your looking to develop on your windows machine had you considered using a GUI like PhpMyAdmin? (if your intending to code in PHP I can highly recommend XAMPP)

[its really useful and comes with PhpMyAdmin as standard](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: I get: 

MySQL JS> show databases
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I read that "MySQL JS" means Java Script. I want the command-line tool as described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

I just need it for a POC, I want it because it should be fast and simple.